# SQL Server stored procedure inserts second row when it was supposed to read what it just inserted when called with the same parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is executed by passing `CustNum` and is supposed to return `Cust_Key`. If the `CustNum` exists, then it should return the existing `Cust_Key`, else it should insert the `CustNum` into the table and returns the newly created `Cust_Key`.

In the table, `Cust_Key_Initial` is an identity and `Cust_Key` takes the value of `Cust_Key_Initial` initially. Table is designed like so because `Cust_Key` could change but `Cust_Key_Initial` will not change.

Now the issue I am having is, once is a while, the stored procedure inserts a `CustNum` to the table twice in a split second difference instead of reading `Cust_Key` for the `CustNum` that was just inserted. I don't understand how this happens, please help me with this. The definition of the procedure is below. Also there is no speed issue here, it usually returns in about 100 milliseconds.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetCustKey
    @CustNum Varchar(10) NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.value_Customer WITH (NOLOCK) 
                   WHERE CustNum= @CustNum)
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO dbo.value_Customer (Cust_Key, CustNum, CustNum_Initial)
            SELECT -1, @CustNum, @CustNum

        UPDATE dbo.value_Customer 
        SET Cust_Key = Cust_Key_Initial
        WHERE Cust_Key_Initial = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END   

    -- Return Value
    SELECT TOP 1 Cust_Key 
    FROM dbo.value_Customer WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CustNum = @CustNum
END
```

Comment: Stop splattering [nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). It is not magic and is subject to errors - actual ones and logical ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (imo) a good approach for avoiding race conditions, which it seems is the issue you're having here.  The procedure first attempts to find the Cust_Key_Initial.  If it's found, i.e. @@rowcount!=0, then it's returned.  If it's not found then it's created and used to update the table to set the Cust_Key to equal the Cust_Key_Initial.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_GetPersonKey
    @CustNum Varchar(10) NULL
AS
set nocount on;
declare
  @Cust_Key_Initial     int;

select @Cust_Key_Initial=Cust_Key 
from dbo.value_Customer /*WITH (NOLOCK)*/
where CustNum = @CustNum;

if @@rowcount=0
    begin
        insert into dbo.value_Customer (Cust_Key, CustNum, CustNum_Initial)
            select -1, @CustNum, @CustNum
        select @Cust_Key_Initial=scope_identity();
        
        update dbo.value_Customer 
        set Cust_Key=Cust_Key_Initial
        where Cust_Key_Initial = @Cust_Key_Initial;
    end   

select @Cust_Key_Initial;
go
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SteveC, I will give this a shot.

Comment: More could be said about this.  Because there are 2 dml statements within the begin/end block it should be declared as an explicit transaction with Xact_abort setting.  This would ensure good rollbacks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Cust_key_Initial is not an identity specified column because normally you cannot insert a row determining its identity so SCOPE_IDENTITY returns you either NULL or the value identity on your table which is different from @CustNum

Comment: Sorry Amirhossein, I Just edited the stored proc. There was a typo.